# Is there any way in salesforce where manager login as someone who reports to them?

Tags: login, grant-login-access

Is there any way in salesforce where manager login as someone who reports to them and not able to login as any other user.

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do this with [delegated administration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_delegate.htm&type=5). Unfortunately, each manager would have to be set up independently, so it's not very scalable, but if you have just a handful of users you want to do with this, it's certainly possible.